# Overriding argparse arguments has strange interaction with parent parsers

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm setting up a series of subparsers using ArgumentParser.add_subparsers(), with a common parent parser for the global options I want to be available on either side of the sub-command. For example, I want `command --foo subcommand` to be equivalent to `command subcommand --foo`. The easiest way to do this is to create a separate argparse.ArgumentParser with the common options, and pass it in with `parents=[parent_parser]` to both the main parser and the subparser. This part works.

The problem comes up when I want to override one of the arguments in the parent parser for one of the subsystems. There's a flag that I want to force off (easily done), but more importantly I want the `subcommand -h` information to make it clear that this option is disabled.

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#conflict-handler) says I can set `conflict_handler='resolve'` when constructing the subparser, which would then override the conflicting argument, which I can do. However, when it does this it appears to somehow override the `action` of the parent parser, but not the `default`.

In the following code, if you run it as `argparse_fun.py` or `argparse_fun.py -f` then the output is `Namespace(foo=True)`. If you run it as `argparse_fun.py a` or `argparse_fun.py a -f` then the output is `Namespace(foo=False)`.

Am I missing something? Did I find a bug? Is there a way to do accomplish this that avoids this problem?

Minimum viable code to demonstrate the issue:

```py
#!python3
import argparse

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent_parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', action='store_true', help='Parent foo')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parent_parser])
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='sub parsers')

subparser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', parents=[parent_parser], conflict_handler='resolve')
subparser_a.add_argument('-f', '--foo', default=False, action='store_false', help='disabled for a')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

The output of `argparse_fun.py` seems to hint that it's partially overwriting the parent, in that `-h` still knows that `Parent foo` exists but does not show any args associated with it:

```py
usage: argparse_fun.py [-h]  {a} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  foo         Parent foo

sub parsers:
  {a}
```

If you look carefully, you'll note there's a space between `[-h]` and `{a}` for an argument to go, and `Parent foo` does not have any flags associated with it, but the main parser still knows it has an argument. Very odd.

Comment: Parent actions are copied by reference.  So modifications in one (sub)parser may appear in the parent, and other users of the parent.  Also don't use the same `dest` in the main and subparsers.  Values set by the sub, including the default, will override values set by the main.  In general trying to  provide the same argument in the main and subs is is awkward.

Comment: By reference? Are you sure? The documentation states [https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parents]:

> Note: You must fully initialize the parsers before passing them via parents. If you change the parent parsers after the child parser, those changes will not be reflected in the child.

Comment: `add_argument` creates an `Action` object, and saves a reference to that in a parser's attribute (list).  When a child parser is created, those references are copied to the child's list.  This is done in the `_add_container_actions` method.  The docs warn us that any `Actions` added to the parent after wards, will not be copied to the child.  In other words, the parent-child link is only used when the child is created; there's no persistent or dynamic link - except that the `Action` objects are shared.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's annoying, but that does match the behavior I'm seeing. Hm. I'll have to rethink how I'm doing this, then. Maybe passing the parsers into a function that implements the shared list of add_argument. Hm.